How to load a datetime from SQL Server, separate it in date and time in SSRS and make it filterable in Excel when downloading the report?
How can I use a datetime column from SQL Server to have the following behavior when creating an SSRS Report?

In the report I want two columns. One with only date and one with only time.
When I export the report as an Excel file the date column needs to enable Excel to apply its filtering for dates


With Microsoft Report Builder do a double click on the cell in your report's table which shall contain your date. Use the following expression to separate the date from your datetime column.
=DateAdd("d",DateDiff("d",Today(),Fields!DatetimeColumn.Value),Today())

This calculates the days between Today() (date without time) and your datetime. Then it subtracts this difference from today. This leaves you with a date without time information.
Then, in the properties of the column in Microsoft Report Builder, select the following settings:

For the time column use the following expression:
=Format(Fields!DatetimeColumn.Value,"HH:mm:ss")

And use these settings:

Now, if you export your report from SSRS as an Excel file your columns will look like this:

When filters are applied to the column the date filter will look like this:

And the time filter will look like this:

Remember the following: If you use the plain Fields!DatetimeColumn.Value in your tabel in the Microsoft Report Builder and set the format to be a date which includes time (e.g. *2000/01/31 13:30 in the screenshot) you have one column which can be filtered with date and time like this.

